# What is the easiest way a non-technical person can build a site-specific browser on a Mac using Github's Electron?

Tags: web-applications, electron

I'd like to be able to open websites like Trello, Facebook, Facebook Messenger, Asana, WhatsApp Web, etc as desktop apps. I currently use Fluid (http://fluidapp.com/), but I'd like to see if Electron can be used to do the same thing.

Assuming I have a fresh installation of Mac OS X 10.10, I think I need to:

1. Install npm (https://www.npmjs.com/).
   Should I install io.js or node? I have no idea what difference it would make. **Can npm be installed without either?** In any case, this seems to be quite straightforward: Download and install https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v4.0.0.pkg
2. Install Electron (http://electron.atom.io/). This seems simple enough (although I'm not quite sure if this is a prerequisite for Nativefier):

   ```
   npm install electron-prebuilt -g
   ```
3. Install Naivefier (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativefier). This also seems simple enough:

   ```
   npm install nativefier -g
   ```
4. Follow Naivefier instructions (it uses Facebook Messenger as an example):

   ```
   nativefier Messenger http://messenger.com --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --version=0.29.1 --overwrite --badge
   ```

This is the easiest way I could find. Any other suggestions?
Alternatively, is there perhaps a better but more complicated way?

To be honest, answers may need to be dumbed down quite a bit... I'm not a much of a technical person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build an electron app is quite easy. If you just want to run that app just on your machine you don't need to pack the files. If you want send that app to your friends you need to pack them:
http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.32.0/tutorial/application-distribution/

To create such an app I would recomend yeoman (http://yeoman.io/).

1. Install node.js (https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node), because it is neede to use npm
2. Install yeaoman via npm: http://yeoman.io/
3. Install the electron boilerplate via npm: https://github.com/sindresorhus/generator-electron
4. Make a folder for your app
5. Use the terminal and go to the folder app. Type "yo" and choose the electron generator. The whole project is installed by yeoman
6. After yeoman is finished. Open the file index.js and seek after a line with

   win.loadUrl(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
7. Change the url to your website.

Now when you open the app the url should be loaded. I know there are better ways, but I think this should be the easiest way, when you don't have a lot experience with programming.

Comment: Hmm... It seems similar to me with the Nativefier approach. I'll give Yeoman a run and see how it goes. To answer your question, I would indeed prefer to package it as an app so I can choose icons for different websites and be able to launch them using Alfred (alfredapp.com). Thanks!

Comment: Might I also ask what the better ways might be? I'm not really against spending time to learn and understand new things. If you have the time, please feel free to post general directions or point me to relevant websites!

Answer (score 0):

https://webcatalog.io Is an open-source app that provides a GUI to do the same thing you can do with nativefier with no need for manually installing a lot of different packages.